# К сделать свой calendarView в android

Tags: java, android, calendar, calendar-view

можете подсказать какие есть библиотеки или дать ресурсы где показывается как создать свой calendarView или дать код чтобы был такой календарь как на фото.
и сделать так чтобы calendarView и dateView (где вместо даты время) выходили из под autoCompleteTextView

фото1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

фото2

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

фото3 (с время вместо даты)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю что нужный вам результат можно получить используя библиотеки. [Вот например статья](https://medium.com/@Patel_Prashant_/android-custom-calendar-with-events-fa48dfca8257) где обозреваются разные виджеты из библиотек. Я бы советовал обратить внимание на [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-Calendar):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или вот еще пример этой библиотеки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [список библиотек](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/27) по данному виджету.